# Multiple columns transmute (dplyr) without specifying them manually

Tags: r

Could you please help me to find out how to `transmute` certain columns using `dplyr`?

For example, this works just fine:

```
try <- df %>% transmute(BL_AGE,INCIDENT_CVD, KOL = KOL)
```

But, what if I need to include in the above formula multiple columns as `(df)[c(100:200)`?

So that it would take all these columns automatically, without needing to specify them manually.

```
try <- df %>% transmute(BL_AGE,INCIDENT_CVD, KOL = KOL + names(df)[c(100:200)])
```

These columns are just vectors of values, but here I need to call their colnnames as for instance for `KOL=KOL`.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Why are you transmuting so many columns to (what I assume you want) is the same name?

Comment: I would like then to use `try` in following `cox <- coxph(Surv(df$BL_AGE,df$INCIDENT_CVD) ~ ., try)`

Comment: Seems like you can just use `select(BL_AGE,INCIDENT_CVD, KOL = KOL, 100:200)`?

Comment: Oh, yes! Thank you very much! :)